# Find solution for an algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a List<> in c# contains number of objects, for example 100. I need to select some objects in a row without repetition.  For example, I select object 4 and then randomly a random number of sequential objects after that (object 5 and 6). When I want to select another collection, it shouldn't contains object 4, 5, and 6. If I remove these objects from List then sometimes I will receive object 2,3,7,8 that useless. In another words, I need some sub lists from main list without repeated objects and with the same order as main list. I was wondering if anybody help me to solve this algorithm.

Comment: [What Have You Tried?!](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Yes, of course. You could trade this "money" thing against the solution of the algorithm.

Comment: Have you looked at Union and Intersection methods of List?

Comment: I would suggest changing the List<> to a dictionary or KeyValuePair so that you can indicate when an object has been used. Then use BackTracking to find an appropriate range on subsequent calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your objects in a Dictionary so you can keep an extra information for each object, in your case a boolean that tells you if your object has been selected or not, something like that :

```
//initializing the dictionary, any item has been selecte
Dictionary<object,bool> dic = list.ToDictionary(e => e, e => false);
```

and any time you select an item you change the boolean value to true :

```
dic[selectedObject] = true;
```

and when you try to select a new item from your dictionary you only have to skip the key/value pairs having a `true` value.